# Navier-Stokes: formal definition/intuition of "mean flow"?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

In (computational) fluid dynamics there is a notion of **mean flow** that I don't quite understand:

E.g. in the [Wikipedia entry for turbulence modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbulence_modeling#Closure_problem) it says:

> Averaging the equations gives the Reynolds-averaged Navier–Stokes (RANS) equations, which govern the mean flow.

What is this mean flow?

Is it precisely the kind of flow you simulate by Reynolds-averaging? That is after all a type of "mean". Is there an abstract notion of mean flow in some simplification of the Navier-Stokes equations?

Is there either of those two: some very useful intuition behind this idea of mean flow and or a clear definition?